# Adding mysql to my .bashrc PATH

Tags: macos, bash, path

Ok, maybe I'm doing something really stupid.

I'm on OSX 10.6.1.

I want to add mysql to my path, so I add the following to my .bashrc

```
PATH = ${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH
```

upon running terminal, it doesn't work, which I expect, because .bash_profile is not loading .bashrc at the moment.

but if I manually enter bash, i get the following error

```
bash: PATH: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can't have any spaces.  In other words, your PATH setting command should be:

```
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Note the removal of the spaces between PATH, =, and ${PATH}